# Mail merge in Word to tables, grouping by a field?

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

Is it possible to have source data similar to this

| ID | DATA1 | GROUP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D11 | TEST |
| 2 | D12 | TEST |
| 3 | D13 | BLA |
| 4 | D14 | BLA |
| 5 | D15 | BLA |

and use Word to merge the data, **grouping by a column**, so that the grouping column can be used as a header in Word ?

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
TEST
-------
    1    D11
    2    D12

BLA
-------
    3    D13
    4    D14
    5    D15
```

Schematically (pseudo code) my master doc would be

```
<<MERGEFIELD GROUP groupby=1>>
-------
    <<MERGEFIELD ID>>  <<MERGEFIELD DATA1>>
```

I am aware about how to merge as "catalog", so that records come continously in the merged document.

Of course one option is to create multiple output documents then manually edit together. This is not preferred as it's a manual process.

I can use VBA if necessary.